# Google Cast - Receiver Unavailable

Tags: google-cast

I'm just trying to get a simple "Hello, world!" style app to run with the new Chromecast SDK.  Here's the step-by-step I'm following:

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender

To achieve minimal setup, I'm attempting to wire it up via a Chrome App (App, not Extension) as the Sender, and using chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID as the AppID (as mentioned in the tutorial).

It seems to fall apart somewhere between Initialization and Launch.  My call to chrome.cast.initialize succeeds, but when receiverListener gets invoked, the result is always "unavailable".  If I attempt to call chrome.cast.requestSession, it invokes the error handler with an error code of "receiver_unavailable".

A few things:

- I've paid $5 to Google for a Developer account and registered my device

  - Note: My applications list is still empty, is this a problem?
- I've reconfigured the Chromecast device to send the serial number when retrieving updates
- I've rebooted the Chromecast several times (from my Android app)
- The Chromecast is idle on-screen with landscapes flashing beautifully
- My laptop is on the same wireless network, using a basic Linksys router
- It doesn't work if I use "YouTube" or "Netflix" as the AppID either

Any other ideas?  Please help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @ssgg for leading me to this one.

In Windows 7, the shared network must be configured as Home or Work (not Public) Network.  I re-configured it, rebooted my laptop, and it works like a charm!

This link was very helpful:
https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3249268?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try the two Chrome sender apps here:

https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-chrome
https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome

on your own server.  Or you can try

http://www.videws.com/eureka/helloVideos/

If this works for you, then your Chromecast is good and your Chrome and Cast extension are good.

When you want to switch to your own app ID, you need to make sure they're ready in the Developer Console: https://cast.google.com/publish/.

Comment: Sweet, this is exactly what I needed, way better than building my own. :) I'll see if that works.

Comment: I tried both of the examples you posted, and neither are working.  They are both reporting "receiver list empty".  Any ideas?

Comment: Is your sender (or your laptop) on the same wifi as that of your Chromecast device?

Comment: Also have you checked your Chrome version, extension version? https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes

Comment: Yes, they're on the same network, just hooked up to a basic Linksys that I use for Internet access at home, nothing too fancy.  I'll check the version...

Comment: Everything looks to be up to date, I restarted Chrome because there was a later version ready (even though it was already later than the supported version), Chromecast build and Cast extension are both equal or greater.

Comment: Follow this link to do more troubleshooting. https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3249268?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Two other samples to help:

https://github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver

https://github.com/googlecast/cast-sender-tool-chrome

(optionally use the media server to serve media to receiver - https://github.com/googlecast/cast-support-media-server)

If you are using windows and have multiple NIC's active be aware that this is a bug in Chrome with multiple NICs, it has been fixed in Chrome 33.  You can either switch to 33, or use a workaround --> go into Network & Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings -> Alt-N to bring up "Advanced" Menu -> Advanced Settings, then move the Wi-Fi adapter to the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same Issues except that i could see my Chromecast from the Google Cast extension but never from the Sender App.  I've tried all of the tips from the answers, plus the hints from the Google Cast Support Page. Using **Chrome 33** finaly solved the issue.

@Krispy: thanks for guiding me to the Solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you may all know by now, on Windows 7 this is an known problem. Chrome sender applications don't find the ChromeCast receiver. In the GitHub examples you get the "receiver list empty" message. In the ChromeCast issue tracker, this is known as [issue 159](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=159).

Answer (score 0):

One more issue that might lead to "Receiver Unavailable" is that you using non-published application. For this reason any chromecast device must be manually registered in the same interface where you getting APP_ID as a special device used for development reasons. Otherwise device could not reach non-published application with "Receiver Unavailable" error in result.