# Chromecast Chrome sender app receiverListener returning unavailable on some wireless networks

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cast, chromecast

At home, I use a standard consumer wireless router and everything works as expected.

At work, we use a Cisco wireless mesh network and things are not working as expected: I'm consistently getting an 'unavailable' message in my receiverListener that I'm using to instantiate the ApiConfig object.
However, at work I'm able to cast YouTube videos and other Chromecast enabled Android apps.
At work, I'm able to successfully tab cast from the Chrome browser.

The code I implemented is very similar to what is recommended in [the official Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender).

My code can be seen [here](http://dtr4dgjwo9h52.cloudfront.net/audiour.player.viewmodels-1.0.20.js). The setup occurs around line 900. Here is the core of what I'm doing, in case if you don't want to dig through that code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    function initializeCastApi() {
        var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest('F6ADC45B');
        var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
            chromecastSessionListener, receiverListener);
        chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onChromecastInitSuccess, function onError() { });
    }

    if (!chrome.cast || !chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
        setTimeout(initializeCastApi, 1000);
    }
});
function chromecastSessionListener(e) {
    chromecastSession = e;
}
function receiverListener(e) {
    if (e === 'available') {
        self.chromecastAvailable = true;
        $('#chromecastButton').show();
    }
}
function onChromecastInitSuccess() {
}
```

This is live, so you can see more of what I'm talking about on [this sample page](http://audiour.com/zhwuptos).

Answer (score 0):

Your work network, does it have proxy server?

Start your Chrome browser with --no-proxy-server and see if that helps.

Comment: My work network does not have a proxy server. I tried launching Chrome with --no-proxy-server to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I found another post on this subject.  haven't had chance to check it yet, but will when I get home:

- [Google Cast - Receiver Unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590556/google-cast-receiver-unavailable/21635264#21635264)

Found it via a post of the Google Cast Developers Google+ community:

- https://plus.google.com/communities/115742157569103585450

**Except:**

*If you are using windows and have multiple NIC's active be aware that this is a bug in Chrome with multiple NICs, it has been fixed in Chrome 33. You can either switch to 33, or use a workaround:*

- go into Network & Sharing Center
- Change Adapter Settings

  - Alt-N to bring up "Advanced" Menu
  - Advanced Settings, then move the Wi-Fi adapter to the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, making WiFi the most important network did the trick.  Well, not quite!  I disabled all my network adapters, bar the WiFi, and I get "available" in the receiver callback.  Woo-hoo.  That's 6 hours of my life I'm never going to get back.