# Cast to chromecast from Electron app

Tags: electron, chromecast

I am trying to use this repo: https://github.com/GPMDP/electron-chromecast to cast from my electron app to a Chromecast audio.

Using React, I added this in the top of one container: 
`import chromecast from 'electron-chromecast';`

And then, in componentDidMount() I added this:

```
 chromecast(async (receivers) => {
  console.log("test");

  const chosenReceiver = receivers[0];
  console.log(receivers);
  return chosenReceiver;
 }, true);

const session = chrome.cast.requestSession(
  (success) => {
    console.log(success);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

In the requestSession I get the error code "RECEIVER_UNAVAILABLE", and the other console.logs does not return anything.

Is there anything else that need to be configured to at least find a chromecast that is on my local network? I currently have one Chromecast audio and one Chromecast V1 that should be possible to find.

Comment: Check from the [support page](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3249268?hl=en) what else is needed to be configured (Check the if the set-up of Chromecast is correct, cast from google home app, make sure that chromecast is using 2.4Ghz band, check the OS, try on other device, etc...). You can also visit this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590556/google-cast-receiver-unavailable) for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

An example of pure JS implementation of using the Chromecast from Node/JavaScript (and thus Electron) can be found here:

https://github.com/Reggino/chromecaster

(disclaimer, author here)